# Alternative to du threshold

Tags: disk-usage

I am looking for a way to search directories larger than a specific size. I found the following, which works perfectly:

```
# du -sh /var/log/ --threshold=5G
5.3G    /var/log/
```

The problem is that --threshold only seems to be supported in Ubuntu, as when I try on CentOS for example, I get:

```
# du -sh /var/log/ --threshold=5G
du: unrecognized option '--threshold=5G'
Try `du --help' for more information.
```

Does anyone know of an alternative that works throughout CentOS, Ubuntu and Debian?

I should note that I definitely need the equivalent to support the du -s flag (do not include size of subdirectories).

Comment: My Linux Mint (Ubuntu base) says `-S` (caps) excludes subdirectories. `-s` (lower) summarised the entire tree. So I suspect your first and last paragraphs are in conflict. It is not even clear whether --threshold excludes individual items or reported totals. You might find `sort --sort-h` and clipping the output is better.

Comment: You could get (via compiling) a statically linked `du` that has this feature, and put it on to the device.

Answer (score 0):

`--threshold` is a command available in :

- Ubuntu 18.04 / 20.4
- Debian jessie 8 / stretch 9  buster 10
- Centos 7

A big command line  :

```
(
  THRESHOLD='200M' 
  PATTERN='==========---------========----'
  ( 
    sudo find / -type d -print0 2>/dev/null | \
         sudo xargs -0 -P4 -- du -sh  2>/dev/null ;
    echo "${THRESHOLD} ${PATTERN}" 
  ) | sort -h | sed "0,/${PATTERN}/ d"
)
```

Comments :
`-print0` the separator between 2 files is `\0` help when you have space in folder name

`-0` tell xargs to read stream that have a separator `\0`

`-P4` tell to run with a degree of parallelism 4

`0,/REGEX/ d` tell `sed` do delete rows between the first and the row that match REGEX

ps:

This not available in Centos 6

Answer (score 0):

As #EchoMike444 mentioned, the `--threshold` option is available for the `du` command in CentOS 7, but not CentOS 6 and older. Due to my lack of reputation, I'm not able to comment on his solution, but I wanted to say that it works very well. I don't understand the `sed` command very well, so here are some alternative commands that might help you in your quest.

The command that you posted will only summarize the **/var/log/** directory, but it will not include any sub-directories.

`# du -sh /var/log/ --threshold=5G`

If you were using CentOS 7, the following command would display the storage space usage on all directories in the /var/log/ directory tree that are 5G or larger.

`# find /var/log/* -type d | xargs du -h --threshold=5G | sort -hr`

I'm not exactly sure how you are planning to use this, but here's something that might work for you. While the following command will not give you exactly what you're looking for, it will identify the 10 largest sub-directories in the **/var/log/** directory. Anything that sorts above the output of the echo command will be what you are looking for.

`# (find /var/log/* -type d -exec du -sh {} \; ; echo "5G ####################") | sort -hr | head`

If you want to keep it simple, the following command will give the same results as above but without the output of the echo command.

`# find /var/log/* -type d -exec du -sh {} \; | sort -hr | head`

If you are looking for files that are 5G or larger, then the following command will give you those results.

`# find /var/log/ -size +5G -exec ls -l {} \; | sort -nr -k5`